# Let $S$ be symmetric operator on unitary $n$-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normal-operator

(1) Prove that $S-iE$ and $S+iE$ are regular operators
(2) prove that $U=i(S+iE)^{-1} (S-iE)$
is unitary operator and that none of its eigenvalues is $1$

Ok so first part is fairly easy.
As for the 2. part I proved that U is unitary operator, however I'm having trouble proving that none of its eigenvalues are $1.$
I suppose I should suppose the opposite and stumble upon a contradiction of some sort?

Comment: This isn't true. E.g. when $S=E$ (I suppose that $E$ means the identity matrix), all eigenvalues of $U=E$ are equal to $1$. You are probably missing some other conditions, such as $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $S$.

Comment: No, this is the exact question.

Comment: By the way thanks

Comment: @Gregory There must be something wrong with your question since, as user1551 points out, the statement you are trying to prove isn't true. I suspect that the $i$ in front of $U$ is not meant to be there, i.e. it should be $U = (S + iE)^{-1}(S - iE)$.